# Fancybox ipad issue

Tags: ipad, fancybox-2

I am developing a web page using bootstrap and fancybox2. I never use bootstrap's modal windows instead I prefer using fancybox popups which is much more elegant and configurable. I use fancybox for images popups and some forms popup like login form etc. Everything works fine on my PC but when I test the result on my iPad, form popups fail but images popups work still great. I ve checked safari settings and allow popups setting is enabled. Is there any solution for this? I don't get it. A working demo is here http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/portal/public/ under the administration menu item.

Comment: the link you provided is broken

Comment: No it is not, just tested.

Comment: No, it wasn't when I tested ... it may now ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your [script.js](http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/portal/public/js/script.js) file try modifying your fancybox init this way :

```
$('#login-trigger').click(function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    $('#loginForm').find('#result').remove();
}).fancybox({
    padding: 5,
    type : "inline"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it still doesn't work on ipad, meaning no popup window appears. I have applied to the example url i 've mentioned above. But it's strange enough since images popup works fine for ipad. I don't get it.